# Grease pencil stroke wont show while the pen is down

Tags: grease-pencil

Edit: Ok so actually I just noticed the stokes wont show up when its over any kind of 3d object. So like if I have a monkey on screen and im trying to outline the face the stokes wont show up until after I let go, but in open space its fine. Does anyone know how to fix this? Its not the way the GP line is layered its in front of the object

The Grease pencil in 2.8 seems to not show itself when using my drawing tablet until after I lift my pen but with the mouse the stroke is normal

So ill draw a line and not know where its going because of it being invisible which throws my lines off.

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as well. It is quiet annoying. The solution I found is : 
Install the latest blender 2.8 version and try drawing over the 3D object. If the problem persists add a new stroke or grease pencil from object mode and draw on that new stroke/ grease pencil. Adding a new stroke/greasepencil worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you made the same mistake I did, but I made two errors:

1. The Viewport shading option I chose was "Wireframe", which seems to only show the stroke once it's complete, instead of something like "Solid", which shows the live rendering with proper shading. I suspect you specific issue is this, in which case, you can fix it by clicking on the solid circle icon on the top right corner of the view.
2. In my case, I also wasn't zoomed in sufficiently, and so in Solid shading, the lines were too fine to be seen when zoomed out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case 3d-cursor was too close to the camera when i add new GP object. This is was the reason for this "glitch". The solution was to set transform value to 0 for GP object.